# Set path in /etc/crontab for php file

Tags: php, cron

Hello I have to run `cron` which I have written in core `php`.
Path of my php file in

/var/www/html/xplore/crons/examples/example.php

when I go to path of mu file and run script using php example.php it give me proper output.
But How to give path of file in `crontab` I have tried it by using

```
*/2 * * * * root  usr/bin/php xplore/crons/examples/example.php
```

Do you have any idea please help me in to that?

Answer (score 0):

try like below,

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /xplore/crons/examples/example.php
```

*/2 * * * *  It means that cron will run in every 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the file path that you are passing is wrong. You can try this

```
*/2 * * * * root  /usr/bin/php /xplore/crons/examples/example.php
```

if this path(**xplore/crons/examples/example.php**) is correct

Comment: Thanks for the response but still my cron is not running I have specified proper path.

Comment: Can you create a log file and see what error you are getting */2 * * * * root  /usr/bin/php /xplore/crons/examples/example.php > /usr/bin/logfile.log

Comment: It gives me could not open input file I guess some file permission issue.can you suggest which permission should have to open the file I have given 644 permission.

Comment: Yo don't have the execute permission.Try chmod 744 example.php  :- The owner can do anything and the others can only read it.

Comment: It still gives me error Could not open input file: /xplore/crons/examples/example.php

Comment: Can you try with chmod 777 example.php.

Comment: no I have not given 777 permission  the example.php

Comment: Have you given 777 permission to the example.php? Kindly do it and update us w/ the results.